# Taking snapshot of ios launch screen in applicationdidfinishlaunching

Tags: ios

is there any way to take snapshot of ios launchscreen in **applicationDidfinishLaunching**? There are both storyboard and launch images in my app, and it seems hardly to get UIView of launchscreen, besides, **UIApplication.windows/keyWindow** both return nil. So how should I do with this?

Comment: How do you want to take the screen shot? The launch screen is shown before the app is running and is removed when the app starts, so you will never access it programatically.  You can set a breakpoint in `didFinishLaunching` in order to freeze your app and capture a screen shot from the device or simulator that way.

Comment: I think, you can use [Fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane)